# I Need to flatten an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, reactjs

How could I flatten my array of object :

```js
var mylist = [{
    THEMEID: 1,
    TITLE: "myTheme1",
    PARENTID: 0,
    children: [{
        ITEMID: 1,
        NAME: "myItem1",
        THEMEID: 1,
        PARENTID: 1,
        TITLE: "myItem1"
      },
      {
        THEMEID: 3,
        TITLE: "mySubTheme1",
        PARENTID: 1,
        children: [{
          ITEMID: 3,
          NAME: "myItem3",
          THEMEID: 3,
          PARENTID: 2,
          TITLE: "myItem3"
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    THEMEID: 2,
    TITLE: "myTheme2",
    PARENTID: 0,
    children: [{
      ITEMID: 4,
      NAME: "myItem4",
      THEMEID: 2,
      PARENTID: 1,
      TITLE: "myItem4"
    }]
  },
  {
    THEMEID: 6,
    TITLE: "myTheme3",
    PARENTID: 0,
    children: [{
      THEMEID: 5,
      TITLE: "mySubTheme3",
      PARENTID: 1,
      children: [{
        THEMEID: 4,
        TITLE: "mySubSubTheme3",
        PARENTID: 2,
        children: [{
          ITEMID: 2,
          NAME: "myItem2",
          THEMEID: 4,
          PARENTID: 3,
          TITLE: "myItem2"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
];

   console.log(mylist)
```

In a array where are indexes of children are to record in the children array of the parent array
How could I flatten my myList array to obtain a array as this, by having that the indexes of children to record in the children array of the parent:
Example :

```js
var myFLaten = [
{THEMEID: 1, TITLE: "myTheme1", PARENTID: 0, children:[1,2]},
{ITEMID: 1, NAME: "myItem1", THEMEID: 1, PARENTID: 1, TITLE: "myItem1"},
{THEMEID: 3, TITLE: "mySubTheme1", PARENTID: 1, children:[3]},
{ITEMID: 3, NAME: "myItem3", THEMEID: 3, PARENTID: 2, TITLE: "myItem3"}]

console.log(myFLaten)
```

Comment: What are you asking? Your "this is what I'd like" makes no sense. What is `0:1(index children),1:2`?

Comment: Your result example isn't valid javascript.

Comment: **@h2ooooooo** - **@TPorter ** : Sorry,  I have just corrected. To summarize what I want, it is to be able to flatten my mylist array to obtain a result as in the myFlatten array. Roughly, I would like to saugvegarder that the indexes of the children in the children array of the parent: 
Example: 
**Parent0** : {THEMEID: 1, TITLE: "myTheme1", PARENTID: 0, children: [children index 1, children index 2]} , **children1** : {ITEMID: 1, NAME: "myItem1", THEMEID: 1, PARENTID: 1, TITLE: "myItem1"}  , **children2** : {THEMEID: 3, TITLE: "mySubTheme1", PARENTID: 1, children: [index children 1]},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the last children reference in a closure and iterate the given array. On inserting a new object in the flat array, another insert is made with the index of the inserted objects.

```js
var tree = [{ THEMEID: 1, TITLE: "myTheme1", PARENTID: 0, children: [{ ITEMID: 1, NAME: "myItem1", THEMEID: 1, PARENTID: 1, TITLE: "myItem1" }, { THEMEID: 3, TITLE: "mySubTheme1", PARENTID: 1, children: [{ ITEMID: 3, NAME: "myItem3", THEMEID: 3, PARENTID: 2, TITLE: "myItem3" }] }] }, { THEMEID: 2, TITLE: "myTheme2", PARENTID: 0, children: [{ ITEMID: 4, NAME: "myItem4", THEMEID: 2, PARENTID: 1, TITLE: "myItem4" }] }, { THEMEID: 6, TITLE: "myTheme3", PARENTID: 0, children: [{ THEMEID: 5, TITLE: "mySubTheme3", PARENTID: 1, children: [{ THEMEID: 4, TITLE: "mySubSubTheme3", PARENTID: 2, children: [{ ITEMID: 2, NAME: "myItem2", THEMEID: 4, PARENTID: 3, TITLE: "myItem2" }] }] }] }],
    flat = tree.reduce(function fn(parent, children) {
        return function (r, o) {
            var temp = { THEMEID: o.THEMEID, TITLE: o.TITLE, PARENTID: o.PARENTID, parentIndex: parent },
                index = r.push(temp) - 1;
            if ('ITEMID' in o) {
                temp.ITEMID = o.ITEMID;
            }
            children.push(index);
            if (o.children) {
                o.children.reduce(fn(index, temp.children = []), r);
            }
            return r;
        };
    }(undefined, []), []);

console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you **@NIna Scholz**, Just one last question, if I want to add a parentIndex property to children in the temp array, how should I proceed? I would like to keep the parent's index in the parentIndex property of the child. cordially

Comment: do you have an example of what you like to have?

Comment: should the new property get the index of the parent?

Comment: This is a example :  [{"THEMEID": 1, "TITLE": "myTheme1", "PARENTID": 0, "children": [1,2], depth: 1},
{"THEMEID": 1, "TITLE": "myItem1", "PARENTID": 1, "ITEMID": 1, depth: 2, parentIndex: 0},
{"THEMEID": 3, "TITLE": "mySubTheme1","PARENTID": 1, "children": [3], depth: 2, parentIndex: 0},
{"THEMEID": 3, "TITLE": "myItem3", "PARENTID": 2, "ITEMID": 3, depth: 3, parentIndex: 1}]

Comment: yes I just want to register the parent's parentid or index (i'm not sure id index but I think it's more parentid) in a new property that's going to be called parentIndex in children.

Comment: actually it saves the index. if you like to have the parent index, then just take it instead of `index`.